# Laravel 8 - firstOrCreate() doesn't return Default value set in the DB

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

My MySQL DB has a default value set to `0` for field `formed_id`:

```
`former_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

When I use `firstOrCreate()` method to insert a new record, I do not set `formed_id`:

```
$record = Record::firstOrCreate(
   [
      "name" => "myName",
      "nick"  => "myNick",
   ]
);
```

and the output returns:

```
{
   "id": 10,
   "name" => "myName",
   "nick  => "myNick",
   "created_at" => "2020-10-01 00:00:00",
   "updated_at" => "2020-10-01 00:00:00",
}
```

do not contains the `former_id` field set as default, `0`.

---

To get all fileds in the output model, I need to perform a second query:

```
$record = Record::firstOrCreate(
   [
      "name" => "myName",
      "nick  => "myNick",
   ]
);
$fullRecord = Record::find($record->id)
```

in this case the output returns correctly:

```
{
   "id": 10,
   "name" => "myName",
   "nick  => "myNick",
   "former_id" => 0,
   "created_at" => "2020-10-01 00:00:00",
   "updated_at" => "2020-10-01 00:00:00",
}
```

I do not like this solution because I need to perform two queries instead of one; is there a way to get all fields directly from the `firstOrCreate()` insert?

Thank you.

Comment: Try refreshing the model after insert.

`$record = Record::firstOrCreate($details)->refresh();`

Comment: Did you create the table manually or use a migration file? If you used a migration file please may you add the code for it to your question.

Comment: @Prodiger I tried with `->refresh()` but it is the same, always two queries are performed.


@Rwd yes, the tables are created manually; I'm using an existing DB. No Laravel migration used.

Comment: Same thing also happen in `firstOrNew()`  method

Comment: what i did to prevent the second query when it's not necessary is check if `$record->wasRecentlyCreated` is `true`, and if so, _then_ run `$record->refresh()` to hydrate in the default columns

Comment: A cleaner approach, taken from the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#default-attribute-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the @dave solution:

- [Laravel 8 - firstOrCreate() doesn't return Default value set in the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206697/laravel-8-firstorcreate-doesnt-return-default-value-set-in-the-db#comment124173269_64206697)

the final code should be:

```
$record = Record::firstOrCreate(
   [
      "name" => "myName",
      "nick"  => "myNick",
   ]
);
if ($record->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    $record->refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed correct behaviour. It could be highly inefficient by default to fetch a model directly after it has been created.

In your case you could add an `$attributes` property to your model to achieve default properties and prevent having to do another query.

```php
/**
 * The model's attributes.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $attributes = [
    'former_id' => 0,
];
```

Comment: mmhh... but I don't like this solution because I need to keep align the Default fields in the DB with Laravel project.
The fields `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` are returned; why return all the fields is inefficient?

Comment: It is inefficient because you will be doing two queries. `INSERT` and `SELECT`. This will add up quickly whenever you will be creating mutliple at once. But indeed, maybe this does not apply in your case. Regarding having default in one place. Your could add this to your migration `->default((new Record)->former_id)`. Personally I would prefer to keep this hardcoded in migrations. Migrations are a history of your database.

Comment: Ok, but `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` how are retrieved from DB? with a `SELECT`?

Comment: The `id` is retrieved by using [`lastInsertId`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php#L34). Both `created_at` and `updated_at` are set by [`updateTimestamps`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php#L37). You could follow the whole flow starting at [`Builder@create`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L772)